# Mac Pro system test software?

Tags: mac

I just purchased a Mac Pro from a friend and I was wondering if there was a software application that I could use to give it an overall system test (memory, hard drive, graphics, etc.) to make sure everything is working optimally.  Maybe some sort of benchmark software?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[GeekBench](http://www.primatelabs.ca/geekbench/)

Comment: Geekbench only does CPU & Memory performance.

Answer (score 2):

[Apple Hardware Test](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1509) allows you to check the hardware on your Mac. To use it, insert the system DVD that should have come with your Mac, then restart while holding down the 'D' key.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend [Xbench](http://www.xbench.com).  They also have a database online that might have a baseline model to compare to.